# Why am i getting array_values error

Tags: ajax

Can someone please help me figure out why i am getting the following errors only after the first drop down is changed the second time and every time after that. the functionality is as desired.  The second drop down loads correctly, but i get the error messages anyway:

> ```
> Warning: array_values() [function.array-values]: The argument should be an array in _field_filter_items() (line 513 of C:\TFS\Technology Management\Web Properties\ec_landingpages\DEV\modules\field\field.module).
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in list_field_validate() (line 392 of C:\TFS\Technology Management\Web Properties\ec_landingpages\DEV\modules\field\modules\list\list.module).
> ```

```
function try_ajax($form, $form_state) {
    $options_first = $form['field_property']['und']['#options'];

    $selected = isset($form_state['values']['field_property']['und'][0]['value']) ? $form_state['values']['field_property']['und'][0]['value'] : key($options_first);

    $form['field_property']['und']['#ajax'] = array(
        'callback' => 'ajax_example_callback',
        'wrapper' => 'logos-div',
    );

    $form['field_logo'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => 'Logo',
        '#states' => array(
        'visible' => array(
            ':input[name="field_property[und]"],dummy-element' => array('!value' => '_none'),
        ),
        ),
        '#prefix' => '<div id="logos-div">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>',      
        '#weight' => 2,
        '#options' => get_logo_images($selected),
        '#required' => TRUE,        
        '#validated' => TRUE,
        '#default_value' => isset($form_state['values']['field_logo']) ? $form_state['values']['field_logo'] : '',
    );

    return $form;
}

function ajax_example_callback($form, $form_state) {
    return $form['field_logo'];
}
```

Comment: This isn't related to your answer, but I noticed that you may be using TFS source control with your Drupal site.  If so , you may be able to contribute to this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23503494/can-tfs-source-control-tfvc-be-used-for-drupal-website-development